# Get selected DataGrid values C# wpf

Tags: wpf

I want to get selected DataGrid values.
The following codes work correctly, but when the number of rows selected exceeds 10 items, it encounters an error.

error message: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
please Help Me.

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyGrid.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
{
    var item = MyGrid.SelectedItems[i];
    if (item == null) { return; }

    string Name = (MyGrid.Columns[1].GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text;

    MessageBox.Show(Name);
}
```

Comment: What is the ItemsSource of your DataGrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The following codes work correctly, but when the number of rows selected exceeds 10 items, it encounters an error ...

That's because the visual containers for the items that you don't currently see on the screen have been virtualized away for performance reasons.

What you should do is to cast `SelectedItems[i]` to whatever your data object type is and then access the property of this object:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyGrid.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
{
    var item = MyGrid.SelectedItems[i] as YourClass;
    if (item == null) { return; }

    string name = YourClass.Name;

    MessageBox.Show(name);
}
```

`YourClass` refers to the type of the items in the `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource`:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = new List<YourClass>() { ... };
```